# Ajuda lógica com PHP usando Twitter API

Tags: php, javascript, json, oauth2, twitter-api

Bom, a ideia é a seguinte, estou utilizando `API` do Twitter para fazer autenticação de usuários, estou utilizando o seguinte recurso: https://twitteroauth.com.

Usei este vídeo para me ajudar na autenticação, está exatamente igual: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D8pO7tbYlBk&t=32s

A lógica:

**Todos os usuários que autorizarem o aplicativo**, está sujeito a seguir e receber outros seguidores... o Twitter não fornece este recurso, mas é possível fazer utilizando `PHP`, `Javascript`, `JSON` etc...

**Meu problema**

Autentiquei alguns usuários no localhost, **contas fakes**, ao autenticar e autorizar o aplicativo, é salvo o `screen_name` em uma tabela no `banco de dados`, entenderam? Quero fazer tipo uma roleta, um segue o outro automaticamente.

**OBS:** Não encontrei nada nos termos de uso do Twitter dizendo que é proibido. (Se eu estiver errada me corrijam, por favor).

Me ajudem com a lógica?

**Resumindo a pergunta**: Como retornar dados do `JSON` com `PHP` e depois utilizar o `ajax` para roletar isto?

Comment: Acho que minha pergunta pode te ajudar https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/208247/d%C3%BAvida-sobre-api-do-twitter?rq=1

Comment: Eu já vi, o que quero saber, é como os usuários se seguirem, claro quem autorizar o aplicativo.

Comment: Você pode utilizar esse método da API do twitter https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/friendships/create

Comment: @gmsantos, o problema é que não sei usar `JSON` com `PHP`, por isso pedi ajuda com a lógica. Se você tiver uma resposta simples mas que foque no assunto serei grata. Eu tentei fazer um método que retornasse o `JSON` em `array` foi sem sucesso.

Comment: para manipular JSON em PHP você consegue converter para array e vice versa. Em resumo você usará [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-encode.php) e [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: Grata estudarei, se eu conseguir postarei a resposta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### ToS do Twitter:

> Ações de seguir/deixar de seguir automatizadas: Não é permitido seguir ou deixar de seguir contas do Twitter de maneira indiscriminada ou em massa. Ações de seguir de maneira agressiva é uma violação das Regras do Twitter. Examine nossas Regras e práticas recomendadas do seguidor para garantir sua conformidade. Lembre-se de que os aplicativos que alegam conseguir mais seguidores para os usuários também são proibidos, de acordo com as Regras do Twitter.

[Fonte *(fim da página)*](https://support.twitter.com/articles/332985)

> Nunca surpreenda os usuários. Se o seu aplicativo tweeta para um usuário ou realiza ações como deixar de seguir, um usuário deve iniciar isso - e não ser surpreendido.

[Fonte](https://dev.twitter.com/pt/overview/terms)

O Twitter considera como spam:

> [...]
>
> - se você seguiu e/ou deixou de seguir um grande número de contas em um curto período, especialmente de forma automatizada (comportamento de seguir agressivamente ou rotatividade de seguidor);
> - se você seguir e deixar de seguir pessoas repetidamente, seja para criar seguidores ou para atrair mais atenção para seu perfil;
>
> [...]
>
> - se você estiver seguindo de forma aleatória ou agressiva, marcando como favorito ou retweetando Tweets;
>
> [...]
>
> - se você criar contas ou interações de conta enganosas;
> - se você vender ou comprar interações com contas (por exemplo, vender ou comprar seguidores, retweets, favoritos, etc.); e
> - se você promover ou usar serviços ou aplicativos de terceiros que dizem conseguir mais seguidores para você (como trens de seguidores,
>     sites que prometem "mais seguidores de forma rápida" ou qualquer outro
>     site que se ofereça para adicionar seguidores automaticamente à sua
>     conta).

[Fonte *(fim da página)*](https://support.twitter.com/articles/207151)

*Observe que os termos podem ser alterados frequentemente, as informações contidas aqui podem não está atualizadas de acordo, verifique os links para acessar a informação mais recente. ;)*

---

### API Pública:

O OAuth possui um endpoint para seguir outros usuários, ele é exatamente:

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/friendships/create.json
```

[Segundo a documentação](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/friendships/create):

> Allows the authenticating users to follow the user specified in the ID parameter.

Isso será utilizado para seguir outras pessoas, que você especifica o ID, ou seja informando o token da pessoa X, essa pessoa X irá seguir o ID especificado.

---

*A questão [mencionada nos comentários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/208247/d%C3%BAvida-sobre-api-do-twitter?rq=1) se refere a como fazer o login usando login/senha, ao menos essa era a dúvida desta pergunta, isto de fato não é possível usando a API Pública, por razões obvias, isto é explicado lá.*

Comment: Oi, estou utilizando `friendships/create` porém obtenho o seguinte erro `public 'message' => string 'Cannot find specified user.' (length=27)`, obrigada pela sua resposta, eu entendi os termos de outra forma. mas acho que troca de seguidores não é considerado spam desde que o usuário saiba que está autorizando e concordando com os termos escritos no meu site. Você conhece outro tipo de autenticação sem ser do abrahm? serei grata se puder me ajudar. vou marcar como respondido. Não terás respostas melhores que esta.  Obrigada.